# Python module for custom MakeHuman plugin not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, modulenotfounderror

I installed a plugin for MakeHuman in it's Plugin folder (in usr/share/makehuman-community).
However, the plugin cannot load, since it doesn't find it's own, custom module. I tried out a few different things to fix it:
The original line in the `__init__.py` was:
`from standardize import *`
and the folder structure was like this:

```
└── plugin-folder
     ├── __init__.py
     └── standardize.py
```

So, since it was in the same folder, I tried just replacing the line with:

```
import standardize
```

But that didn't work. So I moved back to the first line and changed the folderstructure to the following:

```
└── plugin-folder
     ├── __init__.py
     └── standardize
           ├── __init__.py
           └── standardize.py
```

But still, not working. I have absolutely no experience with python, so I am pretty lost on this one. Any ideas, what's wrong? I think the plugin was written with a relatively old python version originally. Also had to upgrade it from PyQt4 to PyQt5 (in another plugin, but this works just fine. This one here isn't even using PyQt).

Comment: If you look at the bottom of http://www.makehumancommunity.org/wiki/Documentation:Plugin_System, there should be an example plugin preinstalled. Are you able to use this plugin?

Comment: Is `standardize.py` the plugin you installed? Or is the folder `plugin-folder` containing the two files `__init__.py` and `standardize.py` the plugin? Or is none of this the plugin and the plugin is yet another file?

Comment: The plugin-folder is the plugin installed. It is in the plugins folder of makehuman-community.